# Using JasperReports (JasperSoft Studio + JasperReports Library) with ColdFusion 9 Standard Edition

Tags: coldfusion, jasper-reports, coldfusion-9, jaspersoft-studio

So this is my first time posting a question here. If I do it wrong, please, be gentle. :)

I'm trying to find a decent reporting solution at my company and it seems like JasperReports is one of the better (read: inexpensive) ways to go. They've got a newly revamped Eclipse-based banded report editor called JasperSoft Studio, and it looks really slick.

The problem I'm having is figuring out exactly what pieces I need in order to use this tool (or the files it creates) in my CF apps. After much Googling, I'm not really finding the answers I'm looking for... and what little information I *do* find is really pretty old.

Is anyone using JasperSoft Studio in combination with the JasperReports Library to do any on-the-fly PDF creation? We've come to a point on this particular application where cfdocument just isn't cutting it.

The things I know are:

- CF is using a really (really, really) old version of JasperReports
  under the hood to drive cfreport.
- There *is* a way for me to override the really old version of
  JasperReports so that CF will load the newest one.

Beyond that though, I'm not sure if it's just a matter of using JasperSoft Studio to create compiled JRXML files or (.jasper files, I'm not sure which) and then maybe just rename those to '.cfr' which cfreport knows how to deal with... or what?

If I look at the documentation for JasperReports Library it would seem that I need a lot more than just the JR Library and the JasperSoft Studio to make all of this work... but it's just kind of unclear to me. Because the library is so flexible and can be used from lots of different types of systems I'm having trouble figuring out what ***I*** need for my certain set of circumstances.

Is anyone out there using JasperReports in their CF applications or does anyone have any experience setting up to use JasperReports with CF?

There seems to be precious little information on this topic. :(

Also, in case it comes up (as it did in a few of the much older posts I found on the internet) ColdFusion is written in Java so **I DO** have access to any underlying Java Classes that I might need.

Comment: Not sure if it's Railo only or works with CF, but have you looked at https://github.com/denuno/cfjasperreport ?

Comment: I had not @peter. I didn't know that project even existed. I will check it out, and see if it helps me to understand this stuff better.

Comment: @ChrisJordan I am in the same boat as you. Have you solved this problem? I can't believe after so many years, there is no tutorial or guide out there to integrate CF with jesper.